# How to extend Angular's HTTP client?

Tags: angular, typescript

I realise the following code is not valid Angular, however I am just using it to try to visually illustrate what I'd like to achieve.

I'd like to extend the Angular HTTP client to add some headers.

I am imagining making a class that looks like this, where I extend the Angular http client, then in the constructor I set a default header:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http'
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service.ts'

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedHTTPClient extends HttpClient {
    constructor(
        handler: HttpHandler,
        auth: AuthenticationService
    ){
        super(handler)
        this.headers.set('Authorization', this.auth.accessToken)
    }
}
```

Now when I consume it with, for example:

```
constructor(
    authHttp: AuthenticatedHTTPClient
){ }

...

this.authHttp.get('/api/something')
```

The `authHttp` client I am using will already have the header set.
Is this possible?

Comment: Angular has `HttpInterceptors` which can accomplish something similar which will 
allow you to enrich the headers on all http requests https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: Why not look at the source code of an existing open source project like Angular JWT? https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

Answer (score 1):

Angular has an interface, `HttpInterceptor`, that will allow you to achieve the functionality you are wanting in a much easier way.

You can read more about the HttpInterceptor interface here: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: I am currently using interceptors, but I am not a big fan of the pattern. For example, for me to determine if I'd like to add a header I must pattern check the intercepted request url, looking for something that I can use to determine that auth should be attached.

Testing becomes more complicated, because the interceptor is now a testing dependency on actions that have no reliance on said interceptor. Especially annoying when we start working with multiple modules.

I was looking for a more explicit way to attach behaviours to my HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set a Customized Header for each Method...

Maybe it can help you!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppServices {

  public httpHeaders:any;
  public httpGlobalOptions:any;
  public CustomHttpHeader:any;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.httpGlobalOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      })
      };

  }

  methodCustomHeaders(){
    /* Here you set the Custom Header*/
    this.CustomHttpHeader = { 
        headers: new HttpHeaders(
                        { 'Authorization':  'Bearer ABCDEF', 'Content-Type':'application/json' }
                    ) 
    };

    return this.http.get("/your-path-service/", this.CustomHttpHeader);
  }

  methodGlobalHeader(){
    /*Here you use the Global Header */
     return this.http.get("/your-path-service/", this.httpGlobalOptions);
  }

}
```